# Linux Rights issue

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Firstly, I am running all of these commands through www-data user..which is apache2 user...
Using php, and exec function to run these commands...

I create the directory

```
mkdir -p testing
```

Now lets see folders

```
ls
```

the directory testing is not showing...although the folder was created ( I check in physical path)

Comment: Maybe the user www-data has the right to write to the folder, but not read from it?

Comment: To prevent problems with working directory always use a full path instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure that the directory you are writing into a) exists and b) has the right permissions to allow you to read/write to it.

Secondly, try not to use exec, system, or anything like that.  Not only is it unsafe (passing args can be a real security hole), but it also adds a large overhead to the operation, having to spawn new sub-processes etc.

- PHP has a [mkdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function built in
- ls can be replaced by a call to [scandir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Also, using exec() just returns the *last* line of the command you run.  If you really need to use a system program to perform functions then you should either use [passthru()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) to return the data direct to the browser, or [shell_exec()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) if you want to have the output in a string.

Comment: Your answer indicates this is a programming issue. If only the SO folks had read the question before dumping it here... *sigh*

Comment: @DanielBeck pfff.. attach them using an inclined plane wrapped helically around an axis.